# group sequential design for one proportion

Tags: proportion

I would like to create a group sequential design for a one proportion to test H0: p=0.97 vs H1: p=0.98 with alpha=0.3 and beta=0.43.

Above specification provides me the sample size of 120 for a single analysis at the end of 120 subjects. If >=118/120 subjects are responding, reject the H0 in favor of H1.

I would like to conduct interim analysis to stop for futility only.

Please help!

Thanks,
DJ

Comment: $H_0:p=0.97$ and $H_1:p=0.98$? These are not appropriate hypotheses. Also why is $\alpha=0.3$ and $\beta=0.43$, that seems very arbitrary.

Comment: Thanks for your response! We are supposed to show that the proportion is 0.98 or higher and accepted results are>=118/120 responses. Therefore, alpha and beta were calculated based on the accepted >=118/120 sample size. Hope this answers your question.

Comment: Please edit your question and be very precise about what exactly it is that you are doing and why.